# What does "malloc.c:2539: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && ....." mean?

Tags: c, realloc

I'm trying to resize an array in C but i get a runtime assertion

this is the code snippet :

```
        int *v = malloc(sizeof(v) * 5);
        memcpy(v, (int[]){ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,}, 5 * sizeof(int));
        v = realloc(v, sizeof(int) * 6);
        v[6] = 6; 

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
                printf("%d", v[i]); //assertion at this line
        }
```

I get this when i run the program:

```
a.out: malloc.c:2539: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
```

and I don't understand it

I 'm also not getting any warnings

Comment: For which command do you get that message? While there are errors in your program as mentioned in Lundin's answer I can not really see how they could cause that message. Assuming that pointer size is larger than or same as int size and you only access out of bounds after `realloc` the message doesn't seem to match the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got two bugs that may cause memory corruption:

- `sizeof(v)` -> `sizeof(*v)`
- `v[6] = 6;`, this is out of bounds since you allocated space for 6 items not 7. And C got 0-indexed arrays as they taught us in array beginner class.